# Spark SQL hive table error

Tags: java, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get records from a hive table but when trying to make the selection it says that the table does not exist.
The error say `Table or view not found: clientes lines 1 pos 14`

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.MapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Encoders;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        String warehouseLocation = new File("spark-warehouse").getAbsolutePath();
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Java Spark Hive Example")
                .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
                .enableHiveSupport()
                .getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> df = spark.sql("select * from clientes");
        df.show();
    }
```

Comment: Is `clientes` the name of the table? Could it be a typo? Just making sure.

Comment: the name of the table is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is run a SQL on a pre-existing View. 
The View is created with the API `df.createTempView("name_of_view")`.
To access the Hive table in question you need to use the **table()** API as follows : `spark.table(String tablename)` and you get the required Data frame.
You can check before-hand if the table exists in Hives' database with the command `spark.catalog.tableExists(String dbname,String tablename)`. You can refer to these APIs in the JavaDoc for Spark 2
[Spark 2 JavaDoc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/index.html)